# Making a multidimensional list flat where the sublists are equal to their average

Tags: python, list, recursion

So for example, I have the list = [1, [2, [3, [5, [5]]]]] the resulting list would be [1,3].

I currently have this,

```
def avg(mylist):  
    if mylist == []:
        return mylist
    elif type(mylist[0]) == list:
        mylist[0] = 0 # average of mylist[0]
        return mylist[:1]+avg(mylist[1:])
    elif type(mylist[0]) == float:
        return mylist[:1]+avg(mylist[1:])
```

Which works the way I want it too but I cannot find a way to set mylist[0] = the average of mylist[0]. I have also tried it a lot of different ways but I cannot find one that works.

EDIT: Another example of something I tried.

```
total = 0
nosublist=True
if mylist == []:
    return mylist
for x in mylist: 
    if type(x) == list:
        nosublist=False
if nosublist:
    return mylist[:1]+average(mylist[1:])
elif not nosublist:
    for x in mylist:
        if type(x) == list:
            total += average(x)
        else:
            total += x
    mylist[0] = total/len(mylist)
    return average(mylist[:1])+average(mylist[1:])
```

Comment: how the list flat to [1,3]? I did get it

Comment: I assume that you know how to compute an average, so ... please give a clear example or two of what you mean.  Also, please provide basic code to reproduce the problem with one of your failed approaches.

Comment: Are you trying to create an array of all the nested arrays averages or something similar? What's the problem if you were to ask someone else to do it?

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal So the original list [1, [2, [3, [5, [5]]]]] would be shortened each time the function runs, so it goes to [1,[2,[3,[5]]]] then [1,[2,[4]]] then [1,[3]] then [1,3].

Comment: @Prune please read my reply to Jonathan above. Also yes, I know how to take the average. Another example of code in OP

Comment: @galaxyan please read my reply to Jonathan above.

Comment: ahh so you want to create a flatten function where before it flattens it takes the average of its elements.

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't probably the best solution but you could use it help make yours even better! I created two lists on each recursive call one with only elements that aren't lists and one with elements that were all lists *(just in case you had a format like `[1, 3, [2], [2], [3, [5, [5, 5]]]]`)* and created a call stack to take the sum of the elements in each inner array and one to take the length of each inner array and then took the average. Of course since there might be multiple arrays in the list of arrays you can map this same functionality for each array and accumulate their avg's.

## code

```
list1 = [1, [2, [3, [5, [5]]]]]
list2 = [1, [2, 3], [4, 5], [5, [3, 4]]]


def avg(mylist):
"""flattens an array where the sublists to flatten are the average of that sublist"""

  subarrays = filter(lambda x: type(x) == type([]), mylist)
  rootelems = filter(lambda x: type(x) != type([]), mylist)

  avg_all = lambda elem: sum((avg(elem))) / len(avg(elem))

  if subarrays == []:
    return mylist

  return rootelems + map(avg_all, subarrays)

print avg(list1)
print avg(list2)
```

## result

```
[1, 3]
[1, 2, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def isiter(x):
    try:
        iter(x)
        return True
    except TypeError:
        return False


def _flatten(x, reduce=iter):
    for i in x:
        if isiter(i):
            r = reduce((j for j in _flatten(i, reduce=reduce)))
            if isiter(r):
                yield from r
            else:
                yield r
        else:
            yield i
```

Now you can plugin mean

```
def mean(x):
    l = list(x)
    return sum(l)/len(l)

l = [1, [2, [3, [5, [5]]]]]

list(_flatten(l, reduce=mean))
>>> [1, 3.0]
```

or

```
mean(flatten(l, reduce=mean))
>>> 2.0
```

EDIT:

If you really need only a single function:

```
def flatten(x, reduce=iter):
    return reduce(_flatten(x, reduce=reduce))
```

Comment: I had a similar solution to this, but I need it in a way with only one function. If you have any ideas regarding that, I would appreciate it!